# How do you change the css of node editing forms?

Tags: theming, forms

This ought to be really simple -- all I want to do is increase the font size of the textfields in the standard node editing form (node/123/edit).  This should be a trivial tweak of a stylesheet, and I've just spent the last hour adding different bits of css to my standard theme style sheet, with no effect.  Nothing is affecting the style of the fields and I can't even see (via browser Inspect Element) what stylesheet is setting the font size.

Has this changed in Drupal 7?  I'm clearly missing something; can anyone offer advice?

Comment: What theme are you using for the admin area? Is it the same as for your front end theme?

Comment: Make sure to clear your cache after every change to the css.

Answer (score 1):

Arggh -- finally found it.  I'm running a modified version version of Bartik for my site theme, and Seven came along as the admin/overlay theme.  I can put changes into /themes/seven/style.css, and they work.  It all makes sense now, I guess.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Just pay mind to the fact that when you upgrade Drupal, since you modified a core file, it could get overwritten! You may want to make a subtheme of Seven and drop it in your sites/all/themes folder. Hopefully your modified version of Bartik is also in your own themes folder as that is a core theme also.

Comment: Yup. That's just what I've done.